# How to convert chars (Â or Ã or â€) to ASCII codes while creating word document using C#?

Tags: string, c#-4.0, character-encoding, ms-word

I have string `" Single 63”x14” rear window"`  am parsing this string into HTML and creating a word document applying styles using(`System.IO.File.ReadAllText(styleSheet)`).

in the document am getting this string as `"Single 63â€x14â€ rear window"` in C#.

How can I get the correct character to show up in Word?

Comment: What is the text file encoding? How are you writing to the word document?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to find out the incoming encoding of the string

" Single 63”x14” rear window"

And also which encoding the word document allows.

It appears that the encoding characters for those funky quotes are not supported by Word. You could always create a nifty little string parser to search for characters outside the Word encoding range and replace them with either String.Empty, or search for specific supported characters that look similar.

Eg. String.Replace("”","\"");

(this probably wouldn't work without directly manipulating the encoding values, but you haven't provided those so can't give an exact example)

Answer (score 0):

The encoding you are looking at appears to be UTF-8.  It's actually probably exactly what you want, you just need to view it using a tool which supports UTF-8, and if you process it and put it on a web page, add the required HTML meta tag so that browsers will display it using the correct encoding.